# Trying to deploy Vue on Heroku

Tags: javascript, vue.js, heroku, deployment, command-line-interface

im trying hard to deploy Vue.js on herokuapp, im followed this tutorial :https://medium.com/netscape/deploying-a-vue-js-2-x-app-to-heroku-in-5-steps-tutorial-a69845ace489 but when in browse on my website it made me a some error like this :

[image]

CLI return me that :

[image]

On my package.json, i deliberately erase the `build.js` because i doesen't have any file named like this... it possibly that but if add this, it even worse is.

package.json :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: And when you edit your question and show us your runtime logs as text, please include _all_ the error messages, not just what you think is relevant. There's more above this that we need to see.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should set your `package.json` scripts, so that when heroku runs `npm run start` to start your application, you install your application dependencies before it starts running:

```
npm install && node server.js
```

Comment: it made a another error : code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'